# missing method public function index()

Tags: cakephp-2.0

> Missing Method in BusinessController
>   Error: The action index is not defined in controller BusinessController
>   Error: Create BusinessController::index() in file: app/Controller/BusinessController.php.

If I add this method, it brings me to the homepage.  I want to go business_index.ctp

Here is my controller

> App::uses('Controller', 'Controller'); 
>   class BusinessController extends AppController {
>      public $name = 'Business';
>      public $components = array('Auth','RequestHandler','Cache');
>      public $uses = array('User','CreditHistory');
>      public function beforeFilter(){
>          parent::beforeFilter();
>      }
>
> function Sync(){
>          $this->layout = $this->autoRender = false;
>      }
>      //Admin Dashboard
>      public function business_index(){
>          $this->set('title','Dashboard');
>          $uid = $this->Auth->User('id');
>          $this->set('user_id',$uid);
>      }

I have a view name business_index.ctp inside a folder name Business

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could either do redirect $ this-> redirect ('business_index'); in your index method or add router rule in config/routes.php. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html